# Question about multiple ready()'s

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have:

```
<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>
```

Both of these scripts have `ready()` inside.  Will the code in script2.js's `ready()` always execute after the first one?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes.

First of all, the code in `script2.js` will be executed after `script1.js`, as it comes later in the document (and the [`defer` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#adef-defer) is not set).

Furthermore, [the implementation *<sup>[source]</sup>*](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L255) of the `ready` function is:

```
ready: function( fn ) {
    // Attach the listeners
    jQuery.bindReady();

    // Add the callback
    readyList.done( fn );

    return this;
},
```

where `readyList` [seems to be *<sup>[source]</sup>*](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L429) a [deferred object *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). That means the callbacks are executed in the order they have been added to that object.

Comment: Good job Felix. I was just looking at that part of the uncompressed code trying to figure out how to explain it...

Answer (score 14):

jQuery uses its own `Deferred` object for this. The appropriate code of jQuery proves that it is executed in order:

When you call `.ready`, the function is added to the `readyList`:

```
readyList.done( fn );
```

When the DOM is ready, this function is executed:

```
readyList.resolveWith( document, [ jQuery ] );
```

The `resolveWith` function contains this code which executes the functions added as callbacks:

```
while( callbacks[ 0 ] ) {
    callbacks.shift().apply( context, args );
}
```

As you can see, the callback functions are `shift`ed (popped out from the beginning of the callback array (i.e., `readyList`)), so the first gets executed before the second.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple document ready(s) will be fired in order they are defind.

Answer (score 0):

`.ready()` functions are called on first registered get first processed basis

Comment: I would like to see some source attribution for that ... as I understand it it's done with a for..in loop, which means that it uses the iterator over the collection, which you can't gaurantee order using.