# Sync jQuery retrieving from the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, synchronization

I have a personal scripting setup. What I do is write some javascript files in a folder, then a script takes care of joining all of them and minify them.

In two different files, I have this:

FILE 1:

```
...document ready...
$(this).attr('id', 'foo');
...
```

FILE 2:

```
...document ready...
$('#foo').append('<span>bar</span>');
...
```

The problem is, that when it tries to retrieve the `#foo` element, it doesn't find anything, most probably cause it's not created yet. Is there any way to sync this process, so it follows a more proper order? (First create, then append)

Thanks!

Comment: When the script is combined, what order do the functions come in?

Comment: If file1 comes before file2, it should work.

Comment: In my case, the order it compiles is FILE2, then FILE1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "document ready" event cannot make sure in which order your functions are called. I think it would be better if you do not use the "document ready" event for the function in File 2.

Something like this should work:

File 2:

```
...on load of page/element...
'parent of foo'.bind('foo_inserted', 
                      function() { $('#foo').append('<span>bar</span>'); });
```

File 1:

```
...document ready...
'parent of foo'.attr('id', 'foo');
'parent of foo'.trigger('foo_inserted');
```

For more details see e.g. this [page](http://yoan.dosimple.ch/blog/2008/04/30/) or the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Comment: it's triggering a valid and usable solution? I was thinking on that, but didn't know if it was appropriate.

Comment: I am not a jQuery expert, but I think yes, events are made exactly for things like that.

Comment: *"The "document ready" event cannot make sure in which order your functions are called"* ... it can! The functions are executed in the order the have been bound to `document.ready`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6643285/218196

Comment: @Felix: thanks for the hint! The event based solution should be more robust however.